# Scroll down automatically based on which highlighted div on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have page where i have to play certain audio files which are related to the text and when related audio file is played then related text should be highlight. Issue i am facing is that i need to keep the highlighted div visible to the reason. I am not sure how i can automatically scroll down the page to keep the highlighted div visible so that he can read it.

[JSBin Example](http://jsbin.com/notuvodoci/edit?html,output)

HTML

```
<audio id="myAudio">
    <source src="" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
<button>Play Audio</button>
<div class="wrapper">
    <span>Rooster</span>
    <span>Cat</span>
    <span>Horse</span>
    <span>Elephant</span>
    <span>Vulture</span>
    <span>Duck</span>
    <span>Rooster</span>
    <span>Cat</span>
    <span>Horse</span>
    <span>Elephant</span>
    <span>Vulture</span>
    <span>Duck</span>
    <span>Rooster</span>
    <span>Cat</span>
    <span>Horse</span>
    <span>Elephant</span>
    <span>Vulture</span>
    <span>Duck</span>
    <span>Rooster</span>
    <span>Cat</span>
    <span>Horse</span>
    <span>Elephant</span>
    <span>Vulture</span>
    <span>Duck</span>
</div>
```

I tried following code but this not working

```
$aud.onplay = function() {
    $btn.text("Pause Audio");
    playing = true;
    $("div > span:nth-child(" + (audioIndex + 1) + ")").addClass("playing");
    var wHeight = $( window ).height();
    var wHalfHeight = wHeight;
    var x = $(".playing").position();
    var curentSpanPosition = x.top();
    wHalfHeight = wHalfHeight/2;

    //if  ( curentSpanPosition > wHalfHeight )
    //{
    $(".playing").animate({
        scrollTop:  curentSpanPosition
    });
    //}
  };
```

Comment: I have started to explore option of using  `var x = $(".playing").position();`
 `x.top` i will compare `x.top` position with window that height and scroll down. I think this should work

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element

Answer (score 1):

Add the following after `var x = $(".playing").position();` :

```
$('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: x.top
}, 400);
```

[Here is your **updated** code](http://jsbin.com/rumehusato/1/edit?html,output)

Comment: I used following code  var wHeight = $( window ).height();
 `var wHalfHeight = wHeight;
 var x = $(".playing").position();
 var curentSpanPosition = x.top;
 wHalfHeight = wHalfHeight/2;
 
 if  ( curentSpanPosition > wHalfHeight )
 {
  $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: curentSpanPosition
    }, 1000);
 }`